# Mount large nfs folder on small server - is it possible?

Tags: nfs

For example, we have:

- Server `A` with 30 Gb disk space
- Server `B` with 500 Gb disk space. It has `/media` folder (100 Gb - it's more, than whole `A` server disk space)

I want to mount `/media` on server `A`. Will it be ok? If I want to mount 100 Gb folder via NFS, should I have 100 Gb free space on my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has nothing to do with the other. There's no particular reason a server should have local free space to mount NFS volumes.

Comment: So, it will work fine?

Comment: Yes, it will. Why wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

NFS stands for Network File System. It allows you to connect on your server `A` (to mount) a remote folder `/media` of server `B`. You don't copy any file from that remote location to your local storage, you just establish a network link to access this storage.

If your server `A` is formated, the data in `/media` can still be accessed on server B in /media.

If your server `B` is formated, the data in `/media` will not be accessible anymore from your server `A`.

The equivalent of NFS on windows is network drives.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely no issue there. 
You can mount `B:/media` at `A:/somepath` using NFS and there will be no issue.
I have seen many terabytes mounted in a humble SunOS Sparc server.